# using an expression inside XContainer()

Tags: c#, xml, expression

I have two xml files but one file will contain an extra field.  Ideally I would like to add an if statement withing the XElement but I dont think its possible.

Obviously this is horribly wrong, its just an example to give you some idea what I would like to do:

```
    XElement xml = XElement.Load(pfileLocation);

    xml.Add(new XElement("Something",
        new XAttribute("widgit", pwidgitID),

        if (pfileLocation == "file1.xml")
            new XElement("Foo", pfoo),

        new XElement("Bar", pbar)));
    xml.Save(pfileLocation);
```

My guess is that I should pass it into an overloaded method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the ternary operator?  I think this should work:

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load(pfileLocation);

xml.Add(new XElement("Something",
    new XAttribute("widgit", pwidgitID),

    (pfileLocation == "file1.xml")?
        new XElement("Foo", pfoo):null,
        new XElement("Bar", pbar)));

xml.Save(pfileLocation);
```